# Script to give back highest and lowest cpu temp

Tags: bash, scripts, cpu, temperature, conky

I was recently trying to install conky with a custom config, and I wanted a feature that seems to not extst, or at least, as google tells me. I've wrote a simple bash script that reads the cpu temps, checks if it's higher or lower than a old reading, and outputs the correct value for highest and lowest. The thing, is that I sometimes get this error:

```
/home/ffpp/.conky/temphist.sh: line 25: [:: integer expression expected
```

and no temp as a response. The error occurs in almost every `if`, where I compare temperatures with `lm-sensors`, but with random repetitions.

This is the script that I've wrote:

```
type=$1;                                                    #argument import
if [ ! -f /var/tmp/tempmon.var ]                            #check of existence of old variables
then
    hddmin=100
    hddmax=0
    cpu1min=100
    cpu1max=0
    cpu2min=100
    cpu2max=0
else
    . /var/tmp/tempmon.var
fi

case $type in                                               #start of information collection and comparison according to argument
    hddmin)
        tmp=$(hddtemp /dev/sda -n)
        if [ "$tmp" -lt "$hddmin" ]
        then
            hddmin=$tmp
        fi
        echo $hddmin
        ;;
    hddmax)
        tmp=$(hddtemp /dev/sda -n)
        if [ "$tmp" -gt "$hddmax" ]
        then
            hddmax=$tmp
        fi
        echo $hddmax
        ;;
    cpu1min)
        tmp=$(sensors | grep -oP 'Core\ 0.*?\+\K[0-9.]+' | tr -d . | cut -c-2) 
        if [ "$tmp" -lt "$cpu1min" ]
        then
            cpu1min=$tmp
        fi
        echo $cpu1min
        ;;
    cpu1max)
        tmp=$(sensors | grep -oP 'Core\ 0.*?\+\K[0-9.]+' | tr -d . | cut -c-2)
        if [ "$tmp" -gt "$cpu1max" ]
        then
            cpu1max=$tmp
        fi
        echo $cpu1max
        ;;
    cpu2min)
        tmp=$(sensors | grep -oP 'Core\ 1.*?\+\K[0-9.]+' | tr -d . | cut -c-2)
        if [ "$tmp" -lt "$cpu2min" ]
        then
            cpu2min=$tmp
        fi
        echo $cpu2min
        ;;
    cpu2max)
        tmp=$(sensors | grep -oP 'Core\ 1.*?\+\K[0-9.]+' | tr -d . | cut -c-2)
        if [ "$tmp" -gt "$cpu2max" ]
        then
            cpu2max=$tmp
        fi
        echo $cpu2max
        ;;
esac
                                                            #exported variables to tempmon.var temporary file for future use
echo 'hddmin='"$hddmin"'' > /var/tmp/tempmon.var
echo 'hddmax='"$hddmax"'' >> /var/tmp/tempmon.var
echo 'cpu1min='"$cpu1min"'' >> /var/tmp/tempmon.var
echo 'cpu1max='"$cpu1max"'' >> /var/tmp/tempmon.var
echo 'cpu2min='"$cpu2min"'' >> /var/tmp/tempmon.var
echo 'cpu2max='"$cpu2max"'' >> /var/tmp/tempmon.var
chmod +x /var/tmp/tempmon.var
```

Ive tried using `(( "$var1">"$var2" ))` instead of `[ "$var1" -gt "$var2" ]`, in the `if` comparisions, but, a similar error showed up.
What can I do to solve this?

The way to call the script is the next:

```
bash temphist.sh <temperature to compare>
```

for example:

```
bash temphist.sh cpu1min
```

Here, I call the script to give me back, the lowest temperature that the cpu1 has been until now.
The different types of comparitions are the next:

```
hddmin        #Minimum HDD temp
hddmax        #Maximum HDD temp
cpu1min       #Minimum CPU core 1 temp
cpu1max       #Maximum CPU core 1 temp
cpu2min       #Minimum CPU core 2 temp
cpu2max       #Maximum CPU core 2 temp
```

For this script, the needed the packages are `lm-sensors` and `hddtemp` to work properly

Comment: what does *hddtemp /dev/sda -n* say?

Comment: Using the parameter -n gives back only the temp. In a normal situation, executing hddtemp /dev/sdX will give you back the serial or model of you HDD, proceeded by it's temperature. I use that modifier to make things more simpler.

Comment: add an *echo "$tmp"* right after *tmp=$(hddtemp...)*

Comment: Why? It would give me the actual HDD temp. If I add a echo, conky will use the first echo output to show on my widget.

Comment: ...to seen what value it sometimes output.

Comment: Yeah, for that I can execute: watch -n .5 "hddtemp /dev/sda -n". What I don't understand is why the value randomly becomes NULL. Could it be how do I save the values for later use?

Answer (score 0):

I got tired. I think that the problem was in how I saved the values. It seems like, conky made parallel calls to this script, and sometimes, variables won't get saved. So what I did was split all if in different .sh files, and run them separately, and saving the variables to different files